# File name of a BIML-generated package

Tags: ssis, biml

Well, it looks like a simple thing but I can't find an answer. The name of an SSIS package can't contain dots so 'Step1 Load' is a valid name but 'Step1.Load' is not. Sadly, we have a naming standard that uses dots... Can I specify a file name for a package? I use BIMLExpress and VS2019.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem making this Biml work.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="SO.63451166" />
        <Package Name="Step1.Load" />
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

That results in two packages being created with dots in the file name.

[image]

I did notice in build from BimlStudio that it warns of invalid characters

> warning : Warning:Node: SO.63451166: Package Property:Name The name for AstPackageNode SO.63451166 in package SO.63451166 includes invalid characters (/:[].=) for SSIS. The invalid characters will be replaced with underscores (_) when the package is emitted for SSIS. This may cause duplicate names in SSIS if the invalid characters were making the name unique. Please use a name that does not include invalid characters for SSIS.

But, that's only talking about the `Name` property of the package. Everything in SSIS has a Name property that is required and can't contain the aforementioned characters. The physical `filename` can be anything that is valid for your Operating System. Generally the package and the physical file name are similar (file name having the .dtsx) extension but in cases where you specify period, the engine is going to replace with underscores.

Attempting to use a period in the Name of an object in SSIS is going to raise an error of "Property value is not valid."

> The object name "SO.63451166" is not valid. The name cannot contain any of the following characters: / \ : [ ] . =

Using the supplied Biml, the package Name properties are `SO_63451166` and `Step1_Load` while the files themselves are named `SO.63451166.dtsx` and `Step1.Load.dtsx`

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I thought it is an error, not a warning.